# CMake Error: configure_file Problem Configuring File - with CLion

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, clion

I am trying to setup my CLion on Windows with WSL, following the official tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-clion.html

When setting up the Toolchains, and now in the editor, I am getting the same error after the identification of the C compiler and features, C++ compiler and features. The lines causing the error are always the same:

```
configure_file(
  ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_DIR}/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
  @ONLY
)
```

[image]

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 with Ubuntu 20.04, GCC and G++ version 9.3.0.

Please help me diagnose the problem.

Comment: Please provide your error messages **as text**, if possible. You can use images to supplement your post, if the errors have *already* been presented in textual form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I found the solution here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003413779-Troubles-with-WSL-toolchain-Test-CMake-run-finished-with-errors-

To summarize, you should create a wsl config file `/etc/wsl.conf` and add the following lines:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
enabled = true
```

After this you should reboot your wsl (in powershell).

```
wsl.exe -l     // gets a list of your linux distributions
wsl.exe -t *name-of-your-distribution*
```